# $C^\infty$ approximations of $f(r) = |r|^{m-1}r$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, approximation

Consider $f(r) = |r|^{m-1}r$ where $m \geq 1$.

Is it possible to find $C^\infty$ functions $f_n$, such that

1. $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,
2. $f_n' \to f'$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,
3. $f_n'(0) > 0$,
4. $f_n(0) = 0$

and do we get any upper/lower bounds on $f_n$ and $f_n'$, and if so, how do they depend on $n$?

It is possible to find $f_n \in C^\infty$ such that 1,3,4 hold.

It is possible also to find $\tilde f_n \in C^\infty$ such that 1 and 2 hold.

But how about all four together?

Comment: Should be $m>1$.

Answer (score 1):

What about
$$
f_n(r) = \left(\sqrt{ r^2 + n^{-1}}\right)^{m-1}r
$$

Comment: Thanks, are you sure the convergence is uniform (points 1. and 2.)? Is it easy to prove?

Comment: $f_n'$ is uniformly bounded on compact sets, so (1) holds.

Comment: I am not sure about (2) anymore, I could prove uniform convergence only for $m\ge 2$.

Comment: Why only for $m \geq 2$? I calculated $f_n''$ and it seems to be bounded for all $m > 1$, did I miss something?

Comment: $f_n''$ behaves like $r^{m-2}$ for $r\to 0$, which is unbounded. I would be glad, if I were wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, 2. 3. 4. together imply 1. So all you have to do is approximate $f'$ by smooth functions $g_n$ vanishing at $0$ (e.g. using convolution with symmetric test functions), then perturb very slightly $g_n$ so as to ensure $g_n(0)>0$ without ruining the convergence to $f'$, and finally set $f_n(t)=\int_0^t g_n(s) \,\mathrm{d}s$.

Comment: Thank you. But is it obvious that defining $g_n$ as you suggested that 2. is satisfied? AFAIK, given a compact subset $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is a sequence $g_n$ that converges uniformly on $K$. But for a different $K$ there may be a different sequence.

Comment: Using a uniform construction of $g_n$ (e.g. by convolution), the problem you describe does not happen: you get one sequence of functions defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, that converges uniformly on each compact subset. The key words are "convolution" and "regularization", this is described in many books on real analysis.